# MySQL syntax. Is it allowed to use space between table name, dot, and field name?

Tags: mysql, syntax

In MySQL, is it allowed to use space b/w table name, dot, and field name?

e.g., `tableName . fieldName` ?

Is it allowed in other SQLs?

Comment: Speaking on behalf of T-SQL, they are fine.

Comment: what happens when you try it? Or should we test it for you?

Comment: I almost think you could test this faster than asking!

Comment: Trying and revealing that it does not work would not make a question at all. Standards and practice (bad practice) are not the same. Different mysql settings (e.g., strict mode or else) result in different behavior, what may affect the case. Various SQLs may behave differently, what affects code portability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whitespace is officially allowed by the sql standard, and MySQL (and all databases AFAIK) allow whitespace in this situation.

That said, I have lost an hour or so of my life due to MySQL's quirky whitespace requirements in other places, for example:

Space required after `--` for a comment (not SQL standard):

```
-- A comment
--A Syntax error (but a comment in other databases)
```

And this insidious implementation:

```
CAST(something as sometype) -- OK
CAST (something as sometype) -- syntax error
```

And I'm quite sure there are more surprises lurking.

Comment: The latter one depends on the sql mode settings, if IGNORE_SPACE is enbled, then `cast (...)` will work. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/function-resolution.html